# Index/Match duplicate values, need to return specific date

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, max, match

I am creating a dashboard to find record high sales and corresponding date for a specific date of week. For example, I want to find both the record high sales amount and the corresponding date.

I am using the following formulas:

Max -> =maxifs(C$18:C10000,$B$18:$B10000,"="&A7) where C$18:C10000 is the array for sales values, B$18:B10000 is for the day of week (i.e. Mon, Tues, Wed) and A7 is the day of week for the record (i.e. Mon).

Date -> =index(A$18:A10001,match(B8,C$18:C10001,0)) where A$18:A10001 is the array for the date (i.e. 1/1/1999), B8 is the cell reference to Max value above, C$18:C10001 is the array for sales values

The problem I am facing is with duplicate values. For example, say for a Thursday record if the sales value is 200 and the corresponding date is 1/1/1999. However, say on Sunday the sales value is again 200. Then with the current formulas above for the record Monday value it will work fine but for the date it will return the Sunday date. Is there a workaround here?

Comment: Can you share some sample data? It's always better to visualize a problem. Also, can you include what version of Excel you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that you get the same value occurring on the same weekday (e.g. 200 on 1999-01-01 and 1999-01-08)...

One workaround is to use a `MINIFS` or a `MAXIFS` (depending on your use-case) on the date with two filter conditions: the weekday and the value being the `MAX` that you just found:

```
=MINIFS(A18:A10001,B18:B10001,A7,C18:C10001,B8)
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Comment: @dcx2135 If you are happy with it, please accept the answer